# MFMailComposeViewControllerによるメールの送信が失敗してもResultがsentになる

Tags: swift, ios

MFMailComposeViewControllerを使ってアプリ内でメーラーを開きメールを送信しようとしたのですが、うまくいかなく今回質問しました。関連すると思われるコードは下記のようになっています。
ただ、printによるログをみるとEmail Sent Successfullyと出力され成功しています。送信したメールがiPhoneのメーラの送信フォルダに残り続けており、完全に送信できなかったように見受けられました。
どなたか解決法分かる方はよろしくお願いいたします。

```
@IBAction func mail_send(_ sender: Any) {


    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()==false {
        print("Email Send Failed")
        return
    }

    let mailViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()


    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self

    //  件名
    let subject = String(id)
    // mailViewController.setSubject("Bug Report")
    mailViewController.setSubject(subject)

    let toRecipients = ["test@gmail.com"]
    mailViewController.setToRecipients(toRecipients)

    let body = list[row_now]
    mailViewController.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailViewController, animated: true)// , completion: nil
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
        print("Email Send Cancelled")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
        print("Email Saved as a Draft")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
        print("Email Sent Successfully")
        break
    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
        print("Email Send Failed")
        break
    default:
        print("Email Default Case")
        break
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 「うまくいかなく」についての情報をもう少し詳しく説明していただけるでしょうか。あなたのコードをそっくりそのままコピー(もちろん送信先メールアドレスはこちらで受信確認できるものに変更しました)してiPhone実機で試して見ましたが、普通にメールが送信されました。通常は`MFMailComposeResult.sent`が返って来れば「未送信」のフォルダーに残り続けることは無いと思うのですが。何かネットワーク環境やテストに使ったiPhone実機の設定に特殊なものが無いかなどを調べてみて状況が再現できるような情報を取得し、ご質問内容に追記するようにしてください。

Answer (score 2):

それは今のところそういう仕様で、正しい動作です。

https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeresult/1616878-sent

> The email message was queued in the user’s outbox. It is ready to send the next time the user connects to email.

上記の通り、ドキュメントによると`MFMailComposeResult.sent`は「outbox」つまり「送信」フォルダに保存されたという状態を表します。メールが送信されたかどうかではありません。典型的な例としてはネットワークが繋がらないときなどに発生します。「送信」フォルダに保存されたメールは、設定にもよりますが、次にメール.appにアクセスした際に自動的に送信されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
どうやらWifi環境が悪かったため、送信フォルダから自動的に送信できなかったように見受けられました。
そのため、Wifiを切ってキャリアのモバイルネットワークを使用したところ適切にメールが送信できるようになりました。